# External monitor in portrait mode on Vaio Z1 2C5E

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, sony-vaio, portrait

This vaio model has two built-in graphic cards. I would be happy enough if I could run my external monitor at least in Speed mode (using the NVida graphics card) in portrait mode.

Updating the monitor driver did no change. Windows cannot find a more recent driver to the NVida card online.